# Base64 decoding and writing to file in Python sending Base64-String over cgi.Fieldstorage

Tags: python, file-upload, base64, image-uploading

I want to safe an image file to a server folder.
I recive the image over cgi.Fieldstorage. The adress and Base64 String looks like this:

```
http://localhost/upload.py?data={"base64" : "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QEMRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAYdpAAQAAAABAAAAFgABkoYABwAAAOAAAAAkVU5JQ09ERQAASQBtAGEAZwBlACAAbABpAGMAZQBuAHMAZQBkACAAdABvACAAWgBhAHoAegBsAGUAIABJAG4AYwAuACAAQQBsAGwAIAB1AG4AYQB1AHQAaABvAHIAaQB6AGUAZAAgAHUAcwBlACAAaQBzACAAcAByAG8AaABpAGIAaQB0AGUAZAAuACAAZABlADAANgA0ADgAYgA0AC0ANwA4AGYAYgAtADQANQBkADIALQA4ADcANgBiAC0AZABkADYAOQA4ADgAYQAwADcAMgA4ADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/2wBDAAQDAwQDAwQEAwQFBAQFBgoHBgYGBg0JCggKDw0QEA8NDw4RExgUERIXEg4PFRwVFxkZGxsbEBQdHx0aHxgaGxr/2wBDAQQFBQYFBgwHBwwaEQ8RGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhr/wAARCAAyADIDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD7+orj7Y6tqk19Kut3NpHHeTQpFFBCVVUcqOWQnt61S8TX154W0K91bUPEl/5FrGXKi3tsseyj931J4qZSUIuUnZIqMXJqK3Z3tFeJ3/xF1CDwTZ+JtP1DVrwXGWa18m2V40U4dj+6PAyPzFdnoN1deJNItNU0vxRfS2t1GHQ/Z7bI9Qf3fBB4NYU8TRqy5ISu7J/J9TSdCpTjzSWl7fM7miuX/s3Vv+hkvv8AwHtv/jdV9QttYsrG5uE8RXjtDEzhWt7fBIGcHEftXSYnYUVHbyGW3ikb7zoGP1IooA8Y134vaN4C1y20rVHw9/q9wszHgQxtIwEhPTAYDIOODntTPi5rPgvW7RdH8SeNrPQIbWdXuleQAMf4VYkgDkisjxX8FIviN4oOo6jevHpsF9dedAjEOxEjYC9gM47E9eeAK+O9fvrWHWNbsfE8M012moNvjktyY0mi+cQ7iNpbKk7T64xXzePxFem3TqU+aEn57K19v1PZ4fwUsZVryrVFDltyapXbT730uuivqfROkePF8L+Jp7uGWPVtFt/NhggSQNH5LbV3KRkNlI48duPevpjwvPpd1odpN4eihg0+Vd6RwqFVCeSMDgHJOfevzdvNJ11tHsbfw9eQ6Lc20iOCowuF/hIGQRnmvZvh5+0Fr3gbTY9P16Oz1iMSN5kxX7OxKqoZuPlHI6Ae/UmvJyzMqWHcvazum3ZWu0fT43h3HVkuWnZpLdpJ/ifalUNb/wCQNqH/AF7Sf+gmvK/C37Sfg3xCkIu5J9LmkjWQLMmV2t0O4dvriu+m8T6PrmiXzaRqdpeBreTAimDH7p7V9hSxeHr/AMOaf5/cfH4jL8Xhf41Npd7affsddZf8edv/ANcl/lRSWBzY23/XJP5Ciuo885ezum0qW/gu7O+LNezyqYrOSVSruWUhlBHQ/hXkV/8AA7QL/wAet4jlu/ER02XVV1ifRW0p2t5LwAfPkpnaSoJXnPPrX0bRSaT3Gm1qjyu78F+CL0kz+EJMnqU0iZP/AEFRXG+M/gb4G8T6M1np+iXuk3QmWZLj+yJ7hcjgq0bDDKQenHOD2r6GornWFw6lzKCv6I7Hj8XKDg6srPpd2/M8H0D4QfD/AEHS9PtJfDeoXk9raRW8lw+n3QM2xcbioGBnk47Zrcbw14PsbaX+x/Cs8N6sbeQ40ifcHwcYYrxXrlFCwuHi+ZU1f0Q5Y/GSjySqya7cz/zK1jHJFY20ci4dIlVh7gCirNFdJwhRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQB/9k="}
```

As far as I found out Python uses the Standard 'Base64' encoding for RFC 3548 or RFC 4648, so the String should be alright.

I try this code:

```
def getParam():
     import json
     import cgi
     form3 = cgi.FieldStorage()
     form2 = form3["data"].value
     form1 =json.loads(form2)
     return(form1) 

a = getParam()
import base64
print(a["base64"])
imgdata = base64.b64decode(a["base64"])
print("----------------------------------------------")
print(imgdata)
filename = '/var/www/images/some_image.jpg'
t = open(filename, "wb")
t.write(base64.b64decode(a["base64"]))
t.close()
print(filename)
```

the response if I execute is

```
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 Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3 Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3 Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD7 orj7Y6tqk19Kut3NpHHeTQpFFBCVVUcqOWQnt61S8TX154W0K91bUPEl/5FrGXKi3tsseyj931J4qZSUIuUnZIqMXJqK3Z3tFeJ3/xF1CDwTZ JtP1DVrwXGWa18m2V40U4dj 6PAyPzFdnoN1deJNItNU0vxRfS2t1GHQ/Z7bI9Qf3fBB4NYU8TRqy5ISu7J/J9TSdCpTjzSWl7fM7miuX/s3Vv hkvv8AwHtv/jdV9QttYsrG5uE8RXjtDEzhWt7fBIGcHEftXSYnYUVHbyGW3ikb7zoGP1IooA8Y134vaN4C1y20rVHw9/q9wszHgQxtIwEhPTAYDIOODntTPi5rPgvW7RdH8SeNrPQIbWdXuleQAMf4VYkgDkisjxX8FIviN4oOo6jevHpsF9dedAjEOxEjYC9gM47E9eeAK O9fvrWHWNbsfE8M012moNvjktyY0mi cQ7iNpbKk7T64xXzePxFem3TqU aEn57K19v1PZ4fwUsZVryrVFDltyapXbT730uuivqfROkePF8L Jp7uGWPVtFt/NhggSQNH5LbV3KRkNlI48duPevpjwvPpd1odpN4eihg0 Vd6RwqFVCeSMDgHJOfevzdvNJ11tHsbfw9eQ6Lc20iOCowuF/hIGQRnmvZvh5 0Fr3gbTY9P16Oz1iMSN5kxX7OxKqoZuPlHI6Ae/UmvJyzMqWHcvazum3ZWu0fT43h3HVkuWnZpLdpJ/ifalUNb/wCQNqH/AF7Sf gmvK/C37Sfg3xCkIu5J9LmkjWQLMmV2t0O4dvriu m8T6PrmiXzaRqdpeBreTAimDH7p7V9hSxeHr/AMOaf5/cfH4jL8Xhf41Npd7affsddZf8edv/ANcl/lRSWBzY23/XJP5Ciuo885ezum0qW/gu7O LNezyqYrOSVSruWUhlBHQ/hXkV/8AA7QL/wAet4jlu/ER02XVV1ifRW0p2t5LwAfPkpnaSoJXnPPrX0bRSaT3Gm1qjyu78F CL0kz EJMnqU0iZP/AEFRXG M/gb4G8T6M1np iXuk3QmWZLj yJ7hcjgq0bDDKQenHOD2r6GornWFw6lzKCv6I7Hj8XKDg6srPpd2/M8H0D4QfD/AEHS9PtJfDeoXk9raRW8lw n3QM2xcbioGBnk47Zrcbw14PsbaX x/Cs8N6sbeQ40ifcHwcYYrxXrlFCwuHi ZU1f0Q5Y/GSjySqya7cz/zK1jHJFY20ci4dIlVh7gCirNFdJwhRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQB/9k=
----------------------------------------------
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00\xff\xe1\x01\x0cExif\x00\x00MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x01\x87i\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x01\x92\x86\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\xe0\x00\x00\x00$UNICODE\x00\x00I\x00m\x00a\x00g\x00e\x00 \x00l\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00n\x00s\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00t\x00o\x00 \x00Z\x00a\x00z\x00z\x00l\x00e\x00 \x00I\x00n\x00c\x00.\x00 \x00A\x00l\x00l\x00 \x00u\x00n\x00a\x00u\x00t\x00h\x00o\x00r\x00i\x00z\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00u\x00s\x00e\x00 \x00i\x00s\x00 \x00p\x00r\x00o\x00h\x00i\x00b\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00.\x00 \x00d\x00e\x000\x006\x004\x008\x00b\x004\x00-\x007\x008\x00f\x00b\x00-\x004\x005\x00d\x002\x00-\x008\x007\x006\x00b\x00-\x00d\x00d\x006\x009\x008\x008\x00a\x000\x007\x002\x008\x000\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x04\x03\x03\x04\x03\x03\x04\x04\x03\x04\x05\x04\x04\x05\x06\n\x07\x06\x06\x06\x06\r\t\n\x08\n\x0f\r\x10\x10\x0f\r\x0f\x0e\x11\x13\x18\x14\x11\x12\x17\x12\x0e\x0f\x15\x1c\x15\x17\x19\x19\x1b\x1b\x1b\x10\x14\x1d\x1f\x1d\x1a\x1f\x18\x1a\x1b\x1a\xff\xdb\x00C\x01\x04\x05\x05\x06\x05\x06\x0c\x07\x07\x0c\x1a\x11\x0f\x11\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x002\x002\x03\x01"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\xff\xc4\x00\xb5\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x03\x02\x04\x03\x05\x05\x04\x04\x00\x00\x01}\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x05\x12!1A\x06\x13Qa\x07"q\x142\x81\x91\xa1\x08#B\xb1\xc1\x15R\xd1\xf0$3br\x82\t\n\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a%&\'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xe1\xe2\xe19y\xb9\xfa:z\xbc|\xbc\xfd=}\xbd\xcf\x9f\xaf\xfc@\x01\xf0\x10\x000\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10 0@P`p\x80\x90\xa0\xbf\xfc@\x0bQ\x10\x00 \x10 @@0@pP@@\x00\x10\'p\x00\x10 1\x10@R\x13\x10a$\x15\x10v\x17\x112#(\x10\x81D)\x1a\x1b\x1c\x10\x9235/\x01V\'-\x10\xa1bCN\x12_\x11q\x81\x91\xa2br\x82\x92\xa3Scs\x83\x93\xa44DTdt\x84\x94\xa55EUeu\x85\x95\xa66FVfv\x86\x96\xa77GWgw\x87\x97\xa8(8HXhx\x88\x98\xa9)9IYiy\x89\x99\xaa*:JZjz\x8a\x9a\xab+;K[k{\x8b\x9b\xac,<L\\l|\x8c\x9c\xad-=M]m}\x8d\x9d\xae.>N^n~\x8e\x9e\xaf/?O_os\xe7\xeb\xffh\x000\x0c\x04\x00\x08D\x0cD\x00\xfc\x03\xee\x8a\xe3\xed\x8e\xad\xaaM}*\xebw6\x91\xc7y4)\x14PBUU\x1c\xa8\xe5\x90\x9e\xde\xb5K\xc4\xd7\xd7\x9e\x16\xd0\xafumC\xc4\x97\xfeE\xace\xca\x8b{l\xb1\xec\xa3\xf7}I\xe2\xa6RP\x8b\x94\x9d\x92*1rj+vw\xb4W\x89\xdf\xfcE\xd4 \xf0M\x92m?P\xd5\xaf\x05\xc6Y\xad|\x9bex\xd1N\x1d\x8f\xa3\xc0\xc8\xfc\xc5vz\r\xd5\xd7\x894\x8bMSK\xf1E\xf4\xb6\xb7Q\x87C\xf6{l\x8fP\x7fw\xc1\x07\x83XS\xc4\xd1\xab.HJ\xee\xc9\xfc\x9fSI\xd0\xa9N<\xd2Z^\xdf3\xb9\xa2\xb9\x7f\xec\xdd[\xe1\x92\xfb\xfc\x03\x01\xed\xbf\xf8\xddW\xd4-\xb5\x8b+\x1b\x9b\x84\xf1\x15\xe3\xb413\x85k{|\x12\x06pq\x1f\xb5t\x98\x9d\x85\x15\x1d\xbc\x86[x\xa4o\xbc\xe8\x18\xfdH\xa2\x80<c]\xf8\xbd\xa3x\x0b\\\xb6\xd2\xb5G\xc3\xdf\xea\xf7\x0b3\x1e\x041\xb4\x8c\x04\x84\xf4\xc0`2\x0e89\xedL\xf8\xb9\xac\xf8/[\xb4]\x1f\xc4\x9e6\xb3\xd0!\xb5\x9d^\xe9^@\x03\x1f\xe1V$\x809"\xb2<W\xf0R/\x88\xde(:\x8e\xa3z\xf1\xe9\xb0_]y\xd0#\x10\xecD\x8d\x80\xbd\x80\xce;\x13\xd7\x9e\x00\xa3\xbd~\xfa\xd6\x1dc[\xb1\xf1<3Mv\x9a\x83o\x8eKrcI\xa2q\x0e\xe26\x96\xca\x93\xb4\xfa\xe3\x15\xf3x\xfcEzm\xd3\xa9F\x84\x9f\x9e\xca\xd7\xdb\xf5=\x9e\x1f\xc1K\x19V\xbc\xabTP\xe5\xb7&\xa9]\xb4\xfb\xdfK\xae\x8a\xfa\x9fD\xe9\x1e<_\x0b&\x9e\xee\x19c\xd5\xb4[\x7f6\x18 I\x03G\xe4\xb6\xd5\xdc\xa4d6R8\xf1\xdb\x8fz\xfac\xc2\xf3\xe9wZ\x1d\xa4\xde\x1e\x8a\x184U\xde\x91\xc2\xa1U\t\xe4\x8c\x0e\x01\xc99\xf7\xaf\xcd\xdb\xcd\']m\x1e\xc6\xdf\xc3\xd7\x90\xe8\xb76\xd2#\x82\xa3\x0b\x85\xfe\x12\x06A\x19\xe6\xbd\x9b\xe1\xe7Ak\xde\x06\xd3c\xd3\xf5\xe8\xec\xf5\x88\xc4\x8d\xe6LW\xec\xecJ\xaa\x86n>Q\xc8\xe8\x07\xbfRk\xc9\xcb3*Xw/k;\xa6\xdd\x95\xae\xd1\xf4\xf8\xde\x1d\xc7VK\x96\x9d\x9aKv\x92\x7f\x89\xf6\xa5P\xd6\xff\xc0$\r\xa8\x7f\xc0\x17\xb4\x9f\x82k\xca\xfc-\xfbI\xf87\xc4)\x08\xbb\x92}.i#Y\x02\xcc\x99]\xad\xd0\xee\x1d\xbe\xb8\xae\x9b\xc4\xfa>\xb9\xa2_6\x91\xa9\xda^\x06\xb7\x93\x02)\x83\x1f\xba{W\xd8R\xc5\xe1\xeb\xfc\x03\x0ei\xfe\x7fq\xf1\xf8\x8c\xbf\x17\x85\xfe56\x97{i\xf7\xecu\xd6_\xf1\xe7o\xfc\x03\\\x97\xf9QI`scm\xff\\\x93\xf9\n+\xa8\xf3\xce^\xce\xe9\xb4\xa9o\xe0\xbb\xb3\x8b5\xec\xf2\xa9\x8a\xceIT\xab\xb9e!\x94\x11\xd0\xfe\x15\xe4W\xff\x00\x03\xb4\x0b\xff\x00\x1e\xb7\x88\xe5\xbb\xf1\x11\xd3e\xd5WX\x9fEm)\xda\xdeK\xc0\x07\xcf\x92\x99\xdaJ\x82W\x9c\xf3\xeb_F\xd1I\xa4\xf7\x1amj\x8f+\xbb\xf0P\x8b\xd2L\xc4$\xc9\xeaSH\x99?\xf0\x04\x15\x15\xc63\xf8\x1b\xe0o\x13\xe8\xcdg\xa6%\xee\x93t&Y\x92\xe3\xc8\x9e\xe1r8*\xd1\xb0\xc3)\x07\xa7\x1c\xe0\xf6\xaf\xa1\xa8\xaeu\x85\xc3\xa9s(+\xfa#\xb1\xe3\xf1r\x83\x83\xab+>\x97v\xfc\xcf\x07\xd0>\x10|?\xc0\x10t\xbd>\xd2_\r\xea\x17\x93\xda\xdaEo%\xc2}\xd03l\\n*\x06\x06y8\xed\x9a\xdco\rx>\xc6\xda_\x1f\xc2\xb3\xc3z\xb1\xb7\x90\xe3H\x9fp|\x1ca\x8a\xf1^\xb9E\x0b\x0b\x87\x89\x955\x7fD9c\xf1\x92\x8f$\xaa\xc9\xae\xdc\xcf\xfc\xca\xd61\xc9\x15\x8d\xb4r.\x1d"Ua\xee\x00\xa2\xac\xd1]\'\x08QE\x14\x00QE\x14\x00QE\x14\x00QE\x14\x01\xff\xd9'
/var/www/images/some_image.jpg
```

Problem is I can't open the file generated this way (Unsupported marker type 0x68). Why?

Edit: I just recognized that after the String is loaded `+` is replaced with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hand over data via adress bar, `+` is automatically converted to an empty space. Just string.replace(' ', '+') on the Base64-String and you should be fine.